# theme_preprocess_views_view_fields() function in drupal7 does not accept static variable as index

Tags: theming

This is my code

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
{
    static $i = 0;
    $variables['address'] = t($variables['view']->result[$i]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri']);
    $variables['address1'] = t($variables['view']->result[0]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri']);
    $i++;
}
```

I wrote the following code in *views-view-fields-VIEWNAME--page.tpl.php* :

```
<?php print $address; ?>
<?php print $address1; ?>
```

the second `print` successfully printed its relevant value but the first one displayed nothing.

I tried to use this trick but i failed :

```
<?php
if($i==0)
    $variables['address'] = t($variables['view']->result[0]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri'];
if($i==1)
    $variables['address'] = t($variables['view']->result[1]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri'];
.
.
.

?>
```

why can't I use static variable as index?

---

**UPDATE**

after useful comment of [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) and [arpitr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/11584/arpitr) I modified my code and I created two `THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields` functions separately as follow:

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
{
    static $i = 0;
    $view = $variables['view'];
    if($view->name == "MY_VIEW_NAME")
    {
    $variables['address'] = t($variables['view']->result[$i]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri']);
    $i++;
     }
}
```

and this one

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
{
    static $i = 0;
    $view = $variables['view'];
    if($view->name == "MY_VIEW_NAME")
    {
    $variables['address'] = t($variables['view']->result[$i]->field_address[0]['raw']['uri']);
     }
}
```

for the upper one it was the result

```
Array
```

and the second one (without `$i++`) successfully printed the right value.

Comment: do a dpm($i) inside THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields() and check the value it shows, I doubt the variable count is exceeding the value you are expecting result for.

Comment: @arpitr Thanks for your suggestion. I did this, there are three elements but the result was 0 1 2 ... 15 16. so I modified the code and I updated my post. you can see it. thanks again

Comment: got you :), you should rather add this as answer.

Comment: @arpitr it is very helpful but problem did not solve yet and I must complete this project as soon as possible :(

Comment: The static variables work fine for me. I just want to make sure you are using the correct spelling of properties here: usually, the field name in the `$result` array is referenced as `field_<field_machine_name>`, which, in your case would be `field_field_address` an NOT `field_address`.

Comment: @pamatt then why when I use 0 or 1 as index it works?

Comment: If you are still stuck at that send more info, such as what kind of field exactly is field_address (I assume it would be a contrib module's field, but which?), and what is the content of the array you printed. An outline of what arre you trying to do exactly would be a premium. And please be aware that the answer provided by @clive is a solid one to your original question...

Answer (score 1):

Static vars aren't special beyond persisting inside the scope of the function they were created, for the duration of a single page build. You categorically **can** use a static var as an array index.

Take the following code:

```
function some_test(&$variables) {
  static $i = 0;
  print $variables[$i];
  $i++;
}

$variables = array(
  0 => 'test1',
  1 => 'test2',
);

some_test($variables);
some_test($variables);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
test1
test2
```

Proving that `$variables[$i]` is accessed as expected.

The problem with you code must be somewhere else, as it's not being caused by a language issue as you suggest.

At a wild guess, `$variables['view']->result` isn't keyed in the same way you expect it to be (possibly keyed by the result's base table ID instead of a zero-based list). Dumping out `$variables['view']->result` should tell you pretty quickly what's happening.

Comment: I already dumped `$variables['view']->result`. I updated my post and showed the results and sounds like the problem is not by being `static`

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can tell you I'm afraid - your problem 100%, definitely isn't being caused by the use of a `static` var. It's completely illogical, unless you have a patched version of the PHP language which treats `static` vars differently (highly unlikely that you'd have that without knowing about it). The snippet in the answer above proves the point nice and succinctly - the problem you're having is caused by something else. If I had to guess, I would assume that `$variables['view']->result[1]` doesn't exist